# createBackgroundSubtractor opencv python getBackgroundImage not implemented

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

i am wondering about the behavior of the backroundSubractor Classes of opencv in python according to the  [offical documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/df6/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractor.html) all childs should have apply and getBackgroundImage.
But if i adapt the python example to show the backround instead of the foreground, it works for:

- createBackgroundSubtractorGSOC
- createBackgroundSubtractorCNT
- createBackgroundSubtractorKNN
- createBackgroundSubtractorLSBP
- createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2.

But for 2 it doesn't work:

- createBackgroundSubtractorMOG
- createBackgroundSubtractorGMG

is this behavior intended or something wents wrong?

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
fgbg=cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
#works
#fgbg=cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGSOC()
#fgbg=cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorCNT()
#fgbg=cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN()
#fgbg=cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorLSBP()
#fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(100, 16, 0)

#error
#fgbg=cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
#fgbg=cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()

while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    height = np.size(frame,0)
    width = np.size(frame,1)
    blank_image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    bgmask=fgbg.getBackgroundImage()

    cv2.imshow('frame', bgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: an error occurs like: bgmask=fgbg.getBackgroundImage()
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\bgsegm\src\bgfg_gaussmix.cpp:127: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented)  in function 'cv::bgsegm::BackgroundSubtractorMOGImpl::getBackgroundImage'

Comment: As the message suggests, this functionality was [not implemented](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/bgsegm/src/bgfg_gaussmix.cpp#L127) in those 2 classes.

Comment: is this behavior the same for C? You are right in the python implemantion rise this error intended. But there are 2 possible reasons. 1. there is no backround image or so far no one implement it for these classes. I just want to understand the reason for these behavior.

Comment: That error comes from the C++ implementation, Python is just a thin wrapper around that. It's the second reason -- noone implemented it (the link above shows you that the body of the function consists solely of a statement that throws the error). As for why, you're have to hunt down the original author of the code and ask them. My guess would be that it's difficult/impractical to reconstruct a meaningful background image from the model that's used.